# using opencv haarcascades in android ndk

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like to use the facedetection in opencv cpp to use it in an android app. I have compiled jni successfully. But I wonder how would i use the haarcascades. I can store in sdcard and read it from there. Is there any other way i can use the xml files directly from the project?

Answer (score 0):

There is a c++ example called facedetect coming with the opencv superpack. I'm running OpenCV-2.3.1 myself and it's located in this folder: **../opencv-2.3.1/samples/c/**

The sample uses haarcascades and this might be your best bet for facedetection. If you can use the Android NDK with proper JNI calls from a .cpp file then you shouldn't have any problems to use this sample.

I'm working on a similar thing myself but haven't tried it myself yet. Should be implementing the thing somewhere next week but can't guarantee it. Let me know if this works out for you

Comment: Pimmes111 - Thanks for the comment. I believe that i did not put my question clear. I am already using the facedetect from opencv that uses haarcascades in CPP without any issues. But I want to port it to android NDK. I am facing issues in loading haarcascades because the xml files have to be available in a storage.

Comment: Ah now I understand, must have misread your post a bit. I've scheduled some testing with this myself next week so I'm not sure if it works yet. I think your best bet is to copy the required .xml files to your SD-card indeed and link to them properly. I've came across this link as well **(http://open-nfc.org/documents/FRS_NFC_0910-129%20Generator%20Tool%20for%20Microread%20Configuration%20File%20v0.5.pdf)** to turn xml into a header file (don't know if it works and what the possibilities are but I'll look into it) Maybe it'll help you out?